# Ban discord.js anti word

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I would like to make sure that when a person puts a banned word, the bot bans the person who sent it

Here is the code:

```js
client.on(`message`, async message => {
    let msg = message;

    // Put all the user ID's in this array
    const bannedWords = [`dm.me`, `add`, `dm me`, ` free`, `videos`,`n u d e s`,`see`,`my`,`want`,`guys` ]
    try {
        if (bannedWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
            if (message.author.id === message.guild.ownerID) return;
            if(message.member.roles.cache.has("917037103970402335") === true) return;
            
            await message.delete();
            await message.channel.send(`<@`+message.author+`> **No No No fake **`).then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on Stack Overflow need to be in English.

Comment: You can post in Spanish here https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It's french, not spanish.

Answer (score 2):

With [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) there is 2 methods to ban a member: **`GuildMember#ban()`** and **`GuildMemberManager#ban()`**.

##### GuildMember#ban

[DiscordJS Docs: GuildMember: ban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban)

```js
message.member.ban({ days: 1, reason: 'Blacklisted word' })
```

##### GuildMemberManager#ban

[DiscordJS Docs: GuildMemberManager: ban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=ban)

```js
message.guild.members.ban(
 message.author.id, { days: 1, reason: 'Blacklisted word' })
```